# Migration from EntitySpaces to EntityFramework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entityspaces

Our legacy application is using EntitySpaces for database access but since ES is EoL for several years and is causing some performance issues on our application we're thinking about switching over to EntityFramework.

Is there an easy way to do this without completely rewriting all of our extension classes?

Comment: ouch, is there a lot of tables and data?

Comment: yes, there are a lot of tables and views

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EntitySpaces is alive again and the API has been updated and is far more streamlined. It's a single DLL Nuget install too. What kind of performance issues, I'd love to hear about the issues

https://mikegriffinreborn.github.io/EntitySpaces/

Comment: Would be great, if there was some kind of guide to upgrading from previous versions. We are looking to move away from ES2009 to EF despite EntitySpaces being 'alive and kicking' because of this. But it won't be a simple task..

Answer (score 0):

I've been thinking about this for a while. I don't think there is going to be a simple solution to move away from EntitySpaces and move to EntityFramework. But the approach I would, and probably eventually will take, is if you haven't already, add an interface to each of the methods in your Business logic that inherits from the data classes and include every method you need.

Now, add a Database First EF model and create new business-logic classes for each entity/model to inherit from that interface you've made. Then you know every method that requires re-writing in EntityFramework(LINQ/Lambda). It's a slow process but this way you can do the migration over multiple release windows, slowly moving everything over, referencing the new EF business-logic models as-and-when you have time (and of course, any new tables can use EF straight away).